# Error while Xmx memory allocation to a container

Tags: java, docker, kubernetes, memory-management, jvm

I am trying to set Xmx value in my Dockerfile as:

```
CMD ["java","-Xmx1024m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow","-jar", \ 
...
...
"/home/app/accountowner-extraction.jar"]
EXPOSE 8080
```

I am getting an error as:

```
C:\Users\nisarg>kubectl logs my-validation-app-blhr6
Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx1024m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Below is resource allocation :

```
    Limits:
      cpu:     2
      memory:  2500M
    Requests:
      cpu:      1500m
      memory:   2G
```

Is it because I am not explicitly setting -Xms?
Are there any changes that should be done in memory allocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't write all options in one argument, use separate arguments:

```
CMD ["java","-Xmx1024m","-XX:+UseG1GC","-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow","-jar", \
```

Comment: How can I set these arguments in kubernetes.yaml file?

Comment: With the "args" or "command" properties in the container specification: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#container-v1-core